# Dash - Output of a callback function as Input of another callback

Tags: callback

My code displays a list of n random articles stored in a data frame. I would like to add the following functionality: if a user clicks in one of the articles of the list, display some information of this article. Then, the output of the function generating the list (list of articles) would be the input of another callback function (display this full article). Here's what I've attempted to do, but it seems not to work. Anyone could help?

I've also added the html.Div(id = 'selected-article') on my app.layout to display the value returned by update_selected_article()

```
# Define the callback
@app.callback(
    Output('article-list', 'children'),
    Input('gen-articles-btn', 'n_clicks'),
    State('num-articles', 'value')
)
def generate_article_list(n_clicks, num_articles):
    global articles
    if not n_clicks:
        return None
    
    # Generate a list of articles based on the user input
    article_list = []
    random_df = df.sample(num_articles)
    articles = list(random_df['id'])
    for i in range(num_articles):
        article = random_df.iloc[i]['title']
        article_list.append(html.Li(f"{article}",id={'type': 'article-link', 'index': i}))
    
    return html.Ol(article_list)

#If user clicks on an article, display it
@app.callback(
    Output('selected-article', 'children'),
    Input({'type': 'article-link', 'index': 'all'}, 'n_clicks'),
    State({'type': 'article-link', 'index': 'all'}, 'id'),
    State('article-list', 'children')
)
def update_selected_article(n_clicks, link_ids, article_list):
    # Check if any articles have been selected
    if not any(n_clicks):
        return dash.no_update
    
    selected_id = None
    for i, link_id in enumerate(link_ids):
        if n_clicks[i]:
            selected_id = link_id['index']
            break
    
    # Get the article data for the selected ID
    filtered_df = df.loc[df['id'] == selected_id]
    
    # Create the selected article display
    selected_article = html.Div(children=[
        html.H4("Article Search Results"),
        html.P(f"Author: {filtered_df['authors'].values[0]}"),
        html.P(f"Title: {filtered_df['title'].values[0]}"),
        html.P(f"Headline: {filtered_df['headline'].values[0]}"),
        html.P(f"Content: {filtered_df['content'].values[0]}")
    ])
    
    return selected_article
```